# Why isn't $\frac{0^{0!}}{0!^0}$ not undefined?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got into a big argument with my teacher about this. I am saying that it is undefined because every time I work it out, I end up getting $\frac{0}{0}$ which I know to be undefined.

Comment: What do you get for $0!$ when you work it out? (Hint: $0!$ is not something you can "work  out", it's _given_ by a _definition_.)

Comment: Maybe this will help $0!:=1$

Comment: But it is not undefined. Why wouldn't it be not undefined? (perhaps check that triple negative in the title).

Comment: Triple negations are discouraged.

Comment: There shouldn't have been an argument.  Either the teacher should have said that $0! = 1$ or the student should have listened and realized s/he was assuming $0! = 0$.  Someone wasn't saying something or someone wasn't listening.  Now as to *why* $0! = 1$ which *is* counter-intuitive (have sympathy; it is counterintuitive) is another story altogether.

Comment: "Triple negations are discouraged".  At least they aren't encouraged to not be avoided.

Comment: Can you explain how you got to $\frac00$? That would mean you somehow got $0!^0 = 0$, which is not true since $0!=1$, and $1^0=1$...

Comment: It seems easy to see that the empty sum is zero (the additive identity). The empty product is $1$ - the multiplicative identity. If you assume that all terms of the product are positive, you can convert one to the other using logs/exponentials, if that halls anyone to get why it makes sense.

Answer (score 9):

Conventionally, $0!=1$ and $x^0=1~\forall x\neq0$. From this we obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{0^{0!}}{0!^0} = \frac{0^1}{1^0} = \frac{0}{1} = 0\,.
\end{align}
Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not mere convention. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: But it still is a convention.

Answer (score -2):

> **Hi there, you're wrong - you should apologise to your teacher**

I don't know why this question has gotten so much attention, the OP needs to learn to read and not panic! There is no problem.

$0!=1$ the denominator of $0!^0$ is $1^0$ which is $1$

The numerator is $0^{0!}=0^1=0$

The only problem you could have is if you had $x^0$ with $x=0$, which I consider undefined.

Next.

### Why is $0!= 0$?

There is something I was taught as "the axiom of choice" but it isn't, it has a different name, it states that:

> Given a decision with m outcomes, and another with n outcomes regardless of the first decision then the number of ways to decide is exactly:
>   $$mn$$

If you have $n$ things and you have to choose an ordering, you have $n$ choices for the first thing, $n-1$ for the second, $n-3$ for the third.... so forth. This is where the $n!$ definition comes from

How many ways are there to arrange a collection of 0 objects? One way.

There is only one way I can present you with nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure a student should apologize for challenging a teacher.  Even if the student is wrong.  Now, if the student is pig-headed and never listens is one thing but to simply challenge a teacher is another.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @fleablood